# How to disable eslint rule semi?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, rules, eslintrc

I have a TypeScript project linted with ESLint and `typescript-eslint`.
Here's the rules property in `.eslintrc.json`:

```json
"rules": {
    "semi": [ "error", "never" ],
    "@typescript-eslint/semi": ["error", "never"]
}
```

I have a tsx file, where the last line of the file is

```
export default Main
```

When I run

```
npx eslint file.tsx
```

I get this error:

```
number last string.20  error  Missing semicolon
@typescript-eslint/semi
```

Full `.eslintrc.json`:

```json
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2021": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "plugin:react/recommended",
        "xo"
    ],
    "overrides": [
        {
            "extends": [
                "xo-typescript"
            ],
            "files": [
                "*.ts",
                "*.tsx"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": "latest",
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react",
        "@typescript-eslint"
    ],
    "rules": {
      "semi": [ "error", "never" ],
      "@typescript-eslint/semi": ["error", "never"]
    }
}
```

How to correctly disable semi rules?

Comment: not your issue but if you use typescript don't add both rules, if there's a typescript specific one from `@typescript-eslint` use just that one because the other one is made for javascript and if it doesn't understand the typescript syntax it can show false positives

Comment: zapi, Thank you so much for your answer, the semantic load of which is zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why the rules didn't work when using

```
 "extends": [
        "xo"
    ],
```

so i reinstalled using the command

```
npx eslint --init
```

only this time at the end chose

```
"extends": [
        "plugin:react/recommended",
        "standard-with-typescript"
    ],
```

so the whole file ".eslintrc.json" looks like

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2021": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "plugin:react/recommended",
        "standard-with-typescript"
    ],
    "overrides": [
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": "latest",
        "sourceType": "module",
        "project": "./tsconfig.json"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react"
    ],
    "rules": {
      "eol-last": 0,
      "no-multiple-empty-lines": [
        "error", 
        { 
          "max": 1, 
          "maxEOF": 0 
          }
      ],
      "@typescript-eslint/space-before-function-paren": [
        "error", {
          "anonymous": "never",
          "named": "never",
          "asyncArrow": "never"
        }
      ],
      "@typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises": 0
    }
}
```

in these rules by default is ignored semi.

Answer (score 0):

Use `"off"`:

```json
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2021": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "plugin:react/recommended",
        "xo"
    ],
    "overrides": [
        {
            "extends": [
                "xo-typescript"
            ],
            "files": [
                "*.ts",
                "*.tsx"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": "latest",
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react",
        "@typescript-eslint"
    ],
    "rules": {
      "semi": "off",
      "@typescript-eslint/semi": "off"
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting the same error. That is, it doesn't work. "semi": "off" - doesn't work. "semi": "off" and 
 "@typescript-eslint/semi": "off" - doesn't work